# The file XXXXXXXXXXXX.xlsm has been modified by UERSNAME on [DATE] 12:25:31 +0200

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to copy file from one SharePoint library and to another using custom workflow  activity, after copying I am trying to update this  Author and editor of file name. 
Following is my code,

item["Author"] = sourceItem["Author"];
  item["Editor"] = sourceItem["Editor"];

if (item.File.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
    item.File.CheckIn("Check in");
 item.UnlinkFromCopySource();                                                item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

I am getting following exception to only one document . It is working fine with another document.

Exception
The file XXXXXXXXXXXX.xlsm has been modified by UERSNAME on  [DATE] 12:25:31 +0200.

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that before saving your changes it has some other changes to save,and that causes a conflict and sharaepoint gives this error.

Do you put DisableEventFiring() before performing any updates ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I am not doing anything related to Event Receiver. and It is working for another documents and Working for same document on another environment.